# Calls from Twilio to Google Voice start before pick up

Tags: twilio, google-voice

I'm trying to place outbound calls that will play a recorded message with Twilio. I have the following XML served as TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21</Say>
</Response>
```

When I call a regular landline, it works fine. However, if I call my Google Voice number, by the time I pick up, it's already reading "15, 16, ...". The GV number in question is not using Call Screening, and it's ringing to a single line (a T-Mobile cell phone).

Does Google Voice supervise (connect) the call while it's still ringing? Is this a problem with Twilio's pick-up detection?

Answer (score 0):

My memory of Google Voice is that it plays a message asking for the caller's name before attempting to make the call. I'm betting that is where 1 to 14 are going. Turning "Call Screening" off to connect calls directly may fix this.

Or, Twilio's `IfMachine=Continue` parameter may help you.
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine

Worst case: You may just have to fill the first 10 seconds of the message with "throw-away" text that isn't critical information.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have Google Voice call screening off. I will try to see if "IfMachine" helps, but it's surprising that Twilio thinks the call has been answered when it's still ringing.